# Dubai Transit Twice - Visas

Tags: visas, dubai, transit-visas

We are transiting thru Dubai twice, going & coming, 7 weeks apart, both times we arrive on one airline & leave on another, there is no baggage transfer agreement & I'm want to avoid paying to have it collected if possible. Going we'll be in Dubai for 31 hours, coming back for 15 hours. We are Australian citizens.

I know we can get free 30 day visas which will be fine for going, but they will have expired coming back, I read somewhere that they can be renewed once, but I've also read that they can't be renewed. A 96 hour transit visa each time would work. Are they also free? Can you get a second one 7 weeks later?

Answer (score 1):

The visa that you get is not multiple entry, it is only good for one entry (and exit).

Regarding renewing/extending the visa - you can get a one-time extension, but this is if you are in Dubai and you want to stay in Dubai for longer than 30 days - you cannot extend it once you have exited Dubai - as the visa is only for single entry.

So it doesn't have validity once you have exited the country.

In other words, you'll have to get another visa when you want to come back in.

The visas are free for Australian citizens and there is no time limit between when you can get the visas.